# MATCH function for multiple cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match

I have a formula as below, which checks two cells for a MATCH with Datatable1 (assigned a Name with some data). Here if either of one cell matches with Datatable1, then it writes the value in I7.

`IF(OR((ISNUMBER(MATCH($L7;DataTable1;0))=TRUE);(ISNUMBER(MATCH($O7;DataTable1;0))=TRUE));$I7;"")`

Is it possible to condense the formula with single MATCH function and check $L7 or $O7 matches with Datatable1? Only reason is to shorten the formula.

Comment: Just a note, You do not need either `=TRUE`

Comment: You can try: `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(CHOOSE({1;2};$L7;$O7);DataTable1;0))),$I7,"")` or `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(DataTable1;CHOOSE({1;2};$L7;$O7)));$I7;"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array formula combining COUNTIF and SUM to check if the value exists in Datatable1. Something like this should work:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(DataTable1;$L7);COUNTIF(DataTable1;$O7))
```

This will return 0 if there is no coincidence, and will return 1 or 2 if there is 1 or 2 coincidences. Then you just need to wrap this into your IF:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(DataTable1;$L7);COUNTIF(DataTable1;$O7))=0;"";$I7)
```

If there's no match, return nothing, any case return value at I7

It's more condensed, it's a *shorter* formula.

**EDIT:** After looking @ScottCraner you can add CHOOSE and make it shorter, but as an array formula:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(DataTable1;CHOOSE({1;2};$L7;$O7)))=0;"";$I7)
```

Because it's an array formula, it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

Comment: thank you! ```IF(SUM(COUNTIF(DataTable1;CHOOSE({1;2};$L7;$O7)))=0;"";$I7)``` this suits me very well